# Replacement derailleur 2015 Kona Precept

Tags: derailleur-front

I'm having a hard time finding a replacement front derailleur for my 2015 Kona Precept. It was originally a Shimano SLX but I cannot find a new one that fits.  Its a direct low mount triple with a 44 tooth large chain ring 9 speed.  I've ordered 2 different ones that seemed like they'd work but both hit the large chain ring. the original had a very tall cage that I can't seem to find.  Any ideas or advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: This does not quite make sense. According to the [Shimano Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shimano#Mountain_bike_groupsets), SLX was 10 speed in 2010 with the M663 series.

Comment: Is this the bike? http://2015.konaworld.com/precept.cfm

Comment: Yes Argenti Apparatus.  That is the bike.

Comment: found it thanks

Comment: BikeCe, you have a great opportunity to gibe back to the community: if you answer your own question, even with just the model number, someone else will be able to use that in the future.